# Transfer calls, two iPhone 4, both phones ringing

Tags: iphone

I have two iPhone 4 and I'd like to transfer calls from one to the other. Moveover I'd like to ring on both phones. Is this possible? I know how to transfer calls, but only one phone rings.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The First point is,your carier is providing you the facility  your asking,
if yes then you will get it in the call diversion option.